# Telerik StyleSheetRegistrar() MVC 2 VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik

Help me,

I just begin for trying telerik, but i have an error in register the StyleSheetRegistrar,
here is the code :

```
<%= Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar()
    .DefaultGroup(group => group.Add("telerik.common.css")
                                .Add("telerik.vista.css"))%>
```

and return this error : 'group' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.

at last my searching, it told that all caused by lambda problem in VB9.

any solution please?

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Your searching actually led you to the correct conclusion. There is no lambda support in VB9. The StyleSheetRegistrar (as you see in your question), and all Telerik MVC components, rely on lambda expressions. Really the only way to get around this, from what I know (not a VB.NET expert though ;)), is to utilize VB10 which should have lambda expression support as seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx).